# The Derivative Operator vs $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, notation

For the sake of example, suppose $f(x) = \sin(x) $.
Then,
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)] $$
But
$$f'(0) = 1 \neq \frac{d}{dx}[f(0)] = 0. $$

Why is this the case? Usually, when you have two equivalent functions, they are equal for any value of x. So how can the left side not equal the right side in the second line? (I understand the calculus here; I'm simply confused by the notation.)

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2209823/42969: You can not “differentiate” the equation $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: I would not even say that $\frac{d}{dx} [f(0)] = 0$. Rather, $f(0)$ is not even the right type of object to be input to the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$. That is because $f(0)$ is a *number*, and an input to the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ must be a function.

Comment: @littleO in all fairness you could consider $f(0)$ as the constant function with value $f(0)$ everywhere

Comment: @Lorago That's my interpretation; $ C \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}[C] = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas the expression $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x),$ the expression $f'(0)$ is not the derivative of $f(0).$

Instead, when handling the expression $f'(0),$ the correct order of operation is to differentiate then substitute: \begin{align}f'(0) &= f'(x) \bigg|_{x=0} \\&\neq \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Big(f(0)\Big).\end{align}

In other words, the $f'$ (let's rename it $g)$ in the expression $f'(0)$ ought to be thought of as a function in its own right.

Comment: In other words: $f'(0)=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d f(x)}{\mathrm dx}\right]_{x=0}$ .